# How to create a method for if statements avoid repetition

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

There are three if statements for changeDial that print and add value to the appropriate changeDial, (positiveChangeDial, negativeChangeDial and noChangeDial). These statements are repeated for each of the different 5 currentDial if statements. Is there a way to create a method for the  three if conditional statements. Looking to avoid repetition.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project_5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declaration
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int SENTINEL = -1;
        int currentDial = 0, previousDial = 3, changeDial = 0;
        int value1 = 0, value2 = 0, value3 = 0, value4 = 0, value5 = 0;
        int negativechangeDial = 0, positivechangeDial = 0, nochangeDial = 0;

        // Greeting
        System.out.println(
                "Response Dial Simulator \n" + "-----------------------\n" + "Initial setting: " + previousDial);
        // Execution Loop
        while (currentDial != SENTINEL) {
            System.out.println("Enter the next setting (1-5) or -1 to stop.");
            currentDial = input.nextInt();
            changeDial = currentDial - previousDial;
            // 1 Response Entered
            if (currentDial == 1) {
                value1++;
                if (changeDial < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Negative change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    negativechangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
                if (changeDial == 0) {
                    System.out.println("No change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    positivechangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
                if (changeDial > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Positive change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    nochangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
            }
            // 2 Response Entered
            if (currentDial == 2) {
                value2++;
                if (changeDial < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Negative change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    negativechangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
                if (changeDial == 0) {
                    System.out.println("No change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    positivechangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
                if (changeDial > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Positive change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    nochangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
            }
            // 3 Response Entered
            if (currentDial == 3) {
                value3++;
                if (changeDial < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Negative change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    negativechangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
                if (changeDial == 0) {
                    System.out.println("No change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    nochangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
                if (changeDial > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Positive change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    positivechangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
            }
            // 4 Response Entered
            if (currentDial == 4) {
                value4++;
                if (changeDial < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Negative change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    negativechangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
                if (changeDial == 0) {
                    System.out.println("No change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    nochangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
                if (changeDial > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Positive change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    positivechangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
            }
            // 5 Response Entered
            if (currentDial == 5) {
                value5++;
                if (changeDial < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Negative change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    negativechangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
                if (changeDial == 0) {
                    System.out.println("No change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    nochangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
                if (changeDial > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Positive change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
                    System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
                    positivechangeDial++;
                    previousDial = currentDial;
                }
            }
            // -1 Response Entered Quit
            if (currentDial == SENTINEL) {
                // Response Greeting
                System.out.print("\nResponse Summary \n" + "----------------\n");
                // Count Break Down
                System.out.println("1 was chosen " + value1 + " time(s). \n" + "2 was chosen " + value2 + " time(s). \n"
                        + "3 was chosen " + value3 + " time(s). \n" + "4 was chosen " + value4 + " time(s). \n"
                        + "5 was chosen " + value5 + " time(s). \n");
                // +/- Breakdown
                System.out.println("Positive change: " + positivechangeDial + "\n" + "Negative change: "
                        + negativechangeDial + "\n" + "No change: " + nochangeDial);
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a lot of code, but it can indeed be simplified quite a bit. I would **start** with an `int[]` to represent *dials*. And I would fix the bug(s) with the `nochangeDial` and `positivechangeDial` counters being swapped. And you should test for your `SENTINEL` before modifying any counters. Also, your comments seemed to be noise. Something like,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
final int SENTINEL = -1;
int currentDial = 0, previousDial = 3, changeDial = 0;
int[] dials = new int[5];
int negativechangeDial = 0, positivechangeDial = 0, nochangeDial = 0;

System.out.println("Response Dial Simulator \n" 
                + "-----------------------\n" 
                + "Initial setting: " + previousDial);
while (currentDial != SENTINEL) {
    System.out.println("Enter the next setting (1-5) or -1 to stop.");
    currentDial = input.nextInt();
    if (currentDial == SENTINEL) {
        System.out.print("\nResponse Summary \n" + "----------------\n");
        System.out.println("1 was chosen " + dials[0] + " time(s). \n" 
                + "2 was chosen " + dials[1] + " time(s). \n" 
                + "3 was chosen " + dials[2] + " time(s). \n" 
                + "4 was chosen " + dials[3] + " time(s). \n" 
                + "5 was chosen " + dials[4] + " time(s). \n");
        System.out.println("Positive change: " + positivechangeDial 
                + "\n" + "Negative change: " + negativechangeDial 
                + "\n" + "No change: " + nochangeDial);
        break; 
    }
    changeDial = currentDial - previousDial;
    dials[currentDial - 1]++;
    if (changeDial < 0) {
        System.out.println("Negative change: " + previousDial + " to " + currentDial);
        System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
        negativechangeDial++;
    } else if (changeDial == 0) {
        System.out.println("No change: " + previousDial 
                + " to " + currentDial);
        System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
        nochangeDial++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Positive change: " + previousDial 
                + " to " + currentDial);
        System.out.println("Current setting: " + currentDial);
        positivechangeDial++;
    }
    previousDial = currentDial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method for changeDial and just call upon the method each time.

If would probably go something like:

```
public static int Changedial (currentDial)
{
  //all the code
}
```

That way, your main method has minimal amounts of code, you could also try a switch statement instead of all those if loops.